# Eliminate spikes and lows from Logfile

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have a csv file with logged data from a Temperature/Humidity Sensor.
The rows are: *Date/Time - Temperature - Humidity* (`\t` delimiter)

```
2016-07-21 17:39    36.8    30.4
2016-07-21 17:40    4.7     30.5
2016-07-21 17:41    36.7    30.9
2016-07-21 17:42    36.7     1.9
```

this example shows measurement errors at *17:40 (Temperature)* and *17:42 (Humidity)*

I'd like to loop through the file, find those errors, and create 1 file with all the valid data and 1 with the errors.

My approach:
Iterate row by row and check if the current temperature or humidity values deviate more than 5 °C/% from the previous rows values. (the measurement errors are quite extrem deviations from the regular temperature/humidity)
The Data is written into corresponding dictionaries which are written into csv files.

Here is the code (python 3):

```
import csv
good_data ={} # Dictionary for valid Data
bad_data ={} # Dictionary for invalid Data

with open("path/Logger.csv","r") as f:
    f_reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter="\t",dialect='excel-tab')
    prev_temp = None
    prev_hum = None
    for row in f_reader:
        temp = float(row[1])
        hum = float(row[2])
        if prev_temp is not None and prev_hum is not None:
            if temp < prev_temp - 5.0 or temp > prev_temp + 5.0 or hum < prev_hum - 5.0 or hum > prev_hum + 5.0 :
                    bad_data[row[0]] = row[1:]
                    prev_temp = prev_temp
                    prev_hum = prev_hum
            else:
                good_data[row[0]] = row[1:]
                prev_temp = temp
                prev_hum = hum
        else:
            prev_temp = temp
            prev_hum = hum
```

**Question 1:**
It`s a noob script but it works.
My Problem is, that sometimes the logging process stopped which resulted in a log file like this:

```
2016-07-21 12:00    36.8    30.4
2016-07-21 21:30    16.7    30.5
2016-07-21 21:31    16.7    30.9
```

so in that case, the row by row comparison would eliminate everything from *21:30* until temperature and humidity reach values near *12:00* again.

So I would appreciate some advice on a more elaborate approach to this.

Regarding the edge case:
I am logging Temp/Hum with a Raspberry Pi 24/7 and the first values are ok :-) The edge and lows occur because of some sensor error approximately twice throughout the day. As far as I know it is a bug with the DHT22 Temp/Hum Sensor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you haven't considered the edge case where the first value is a spike or low.

From your question seems like good values are within a certain range [16-38], although a sudden change in temperature/humidity is unlikely when recording values by the minute, they might occur +-5 degrees.

Elaborate approach:
    Find the certain range from the previous day's data, calculate average, mean, deviation to estimate a good range function.